# Kendo Asp.net MVC columnresizing save width

Tags: grid, telerik, kendo-ui

I am trying to save the grid column size following on the telerik sample

```
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/columnresizing
```

this does not work in kendo UI. I am using the latest Kendo Asp.net MVC.

here are the issues I saw:

1) .ClientEvents method is not defined in kendo UI.
   2) GridAction attribute is not defined in kendo.mvc.dll

How can I make this work for Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC?

shouldn't Kendo UI cover all the functions that telerik UI provides? what is the equivalent way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking are the old MVC extensions demos, they are deprecated. Either use the MVC Kendo Wrappers demos (QSF) or if currently using the old extensions check the migration guide referenced [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-mvc-extensions-resources.aspx).